# Adding public class method

Tags: c++

The graph G is represented with an adjacency matrix through a class with the below prototypes. The question is to  add a public class method that deletes a node from the graph (void delete(int)). Please can somebody help me with the code. I have been struggling with this question for days.

```
int V;
structAdjList*array;
Graph(int)
AdjListNode*newAdjListNode(int)
voidsetEdge(int,int)
boolisEdge(int,int)
```

Comment: What graph? we can't help you when you dont post any code whatsoever.

Comment: I am sorry. The problem is that i am not very good at programming. That is what our professor gave me as homework. Only the prototypes are given.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not the exact verbatim task. Please try again and **specify** what you want to achieve. Start by elaborating on the "graph".

Comment: I am as confused as you are. This is exactly the homework that my professor gave to me. It says that i should add a public class method to delete a node from the graph

Comment: So maybe contact him and/or fellow students?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an adjacency matrix, then to remove the ith node, you need to delete the ith row and column in that matrix, simple as that.

How to do that depends on the representation of the matrix. Can't read that from your code fragments. If you had a `vector<vector<bool> > adjacent;` you'd simply use vector::erase (note that this will lead to a lot of reassignments and is not practicable for a big matrix. In the long run, you want a sparse matrix anyway and might opt to simply nullify rows and columns while keeping a list of valid node ids).

Your `structAdjList*array` sounds somewhat like a matrix representation, although that is not clear. I assume that your lecture has material on how matrices are represented during your course. Find that and post that and we can help you further.

In any case, make sure that you don't rely too much on the internet, since you won't have our help during your examn. Consider asking your professor about such things, maybe as spokesman for a group of students who share the same problem (which I assume since else you could simply ask another student).

Comment: That was helpful . Thank you

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the prototypes are supposed to be. You omitted some spaces for sure, like `boolisEdge(int,int)` should be `bool isEdge(int,int);`, but I can't fully reconstruct it. `structAdjList*array;` might be some structure, but why is there a star? Might indicate that the class stores a pointer to a structure called AdjList, which might be a 1d-representation of the matrix - which would not be a good practice. `AdjListNode*newAdjListNode(int)` is also confusing because we have nothing like `AdjListNode` so far. `int V;` is probably the number of vertices, although I'd stick to

Comment: C++ naming conventions and use a lower case name for it. In any case, I'd go with longer names, like number_vertices, or numberVertices. Would do the same with "adjacent" instead of "adj".

Comment: Yeah i understand. Such a confusing question.